# Can you sftp to localhost?

Tags: ssh, sftp

Can you do this `sftp xtydp` where xtydp is the localhost or the result hostname 
I get the error

```
couldn't read the packet :Connection reset by peer
```

So can it be only used to connect to remote server ???

Comment: Yes, you can use `sftp` on any address, including localhost. However, you need to have any SSH server installed on the computer you want to access (i.e. the `openssh-server` package)

Comment: Can you test with `ping xtydp` and/or `ping localhost` that the host name is being resolved correctly to the device IP?

Comment: yes I am able to ping with 0% packetloss but why is this not working

Comment: What happens when you use `ssh` instead of `sftp`?

Comment: Can you post the output of running `nmap -sS -sV -O yourhost`?

Comment: was going through a  linux course and was showing how to connect to remote server using sftp and copy a file to it so wanted to try if that can be done with localhost as I don't have a linux server to which I can copy to

Comment: tcp port is opened

Comment: Ok, could you try to run `ssh yourhost`? Replace `yourhost` with something sensible.

Comment: no ssh myhostname or ssh localhost give me the same output connection refused on port 21

Comment: Usually the SSH port number is `22`, maybe it was a typo?

Comment: sorry my bad it was typo sorry for wasting your time I had installed ubuntu or vitrtual box like yesterday havent worked with it in like few years was brushing up .I installed openssh-server and now it works as intended sorry for wasting your time

Comment: Don't worry, we're here to help. By the way, welcome to AskUbuntu!

Comment: Please, answer briefly your own question using the form below and accept your own answer.

Comment: @Helio thanks for being so generous with your help and encouragement kudos to you and will post this as an answer

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help.